# Configure Symantec Netbackup to send mails about successful and failed backups

Tags: email, symantec, netbackup

I have Symantec Netbackup 7.0 on windows 2008. I have configured backup jobs. I want it to send me  notofications about successful and failed backups.

I can receive notifications about failed backups not about successful ones.

I have done the following steps:

1. I've indicated in "Master Server"->Porperties->"Global Attributes"->"Administrator email address" <-that'why I can receive notif. about failed jobs
2. Also I have written mail address in "Master Server"->Porperties->"Universal Settings"->"Client administrator's email" (have checked "Server sends mail" radio button)
3. Also I have written email address in "Clients"->Porperties->"Universal Settings"->"Client administrator's email"(have checked "Client sends mail" radio button)

What to do? As I said before, I can't get mails about successful jobs.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution:

If you want to receive notifications about just failed backups, then you should write email in "Master Server"->Porperties->"Global Attributes"->"Administrator email address"  JUST!

Or if you want to receive notif. about failed and successful backups, then do the following:

1)  In "Master Server"->Porperties->"Universal Settings" check "Server sends mail"(if netbackup server can send mails) AND if you do this you must check the same("Server sends mail") in "Clients"->Porperties->"Universal Settings" or it will fail.

Note, you also can check "Client sends mail" if client, that is backed up can send mails. But the same should be checked in "Master Server" and "Clients" "Universal Settings"!!! Or it will fail!

2) Write mail addresses in "Master Server"->Porperties->"Universal Settings"->"Client administrator's email" as well as in "Clients"->Porperties->"Universal Settings"->"Client administrator's email"

I have also discussed this in my blog: http://dba010.wordpress.com/2012/03/30/setup-netbackup-to-send-mails/